# Can you derive anything from knowing multiple subaddresses from the same account/wallet?

Tags: privacy, security, cryptography, sub-address, attack

If you can link a known ID to multiple/many (20+) publicly posted subaddresses, and you know those subaddresses are under the same account in a wallet, is there an attack surface here for reverse-engineering any breaking information about the owner of these subaddresses?